# .htaccess remove trailing slash - should be simple?

Tags: apache, redirect

So I have the following .htaccess file in one of my folders (public):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
  </IfModule>

  RewriteEngine On

  # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

I need http://localhost/eamorr.com/lv/public/about/

to redirect to:

http://localhost/eamorr.com/lv/public/about (i.e. trailing slash removed)

But what I'm getting is as follows:

http://localhost/eamorr.com/lv/public/about/

redirects to:

http://localhost/about

(the trailing slash got removed OK, but the path is now wrong!!!)

Can any Apache2 experts suggest anything? I find these redirect rules to be too terse for my understanding.

Here's the complete .htaccess file (nothing else in this file):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
  </IfModule>

  RewriteEngine On

  DirectorySlash Off

  # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=302]
  ###RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=302]

  # Handle Front Controller...
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any rules or conditions above the line? This works for me: RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=302]

Comment: @Xeli thank you for the message. I guess because it was a 301 redirect, my browser saved some info... I changed it to `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=302]` and it seems to work ok now. But the trailing slash is still in the address bar? Do you know how I might fix this?

Comment: So I deleted the cache for localhost in Firefox and the 301 redirect to localhost/about is gone. But the trailing slash is still there. I just need to figure out how to remove the trailing slash...

Comment: That means the rule does not match. Try removing everything from the htaccess file, except for this rule. So you're sure nothing else it making it not work.

Comment: Please see edit to OP for full .htaccess file contents. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You might be facing some `mod_dir` trickery. Try this and see if this helps.

```
  DirectorySlash Off
  Options -Indexes
  RewriteEngine On
  # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=302]
```

Change `302` to `301` when you test it out and see if its working.

Comment: It sorta works... `http://localhost/eamorr.com/lv/public/about/` now redirects to `http://localhost/public/about`

Comment: Where is your htaccess located?

Comment: It's in the public folder

Comment: Why don't you put your .htaccess in eamorrow.com.  This is not a slash issue, this is how your structure is setup. By default the rewritebase for .htaccess is `/` unless you specify it specifically.

Comment: Can't do it that way. I have /mnt/repos as my Apache root. Inside repos are many different projects of mine. One of which is called `eamorr.com`. eamorr.com has a Laravel project called "lv" which has a public folder and a route to "about".